# Test whether effect in one model is significantly higher than effect in other model

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have two models: one predicting the sales for a cheap product and another predicting the sales of a more expensive product (both of the same company). Let us say that both models look like this:

```
Sales = a + b*advertising
```

I want to test whether the effect of advertising on sales for one brand is higher/lower than the effect of advertising on sales for the other brand.

Does anyone know how I can formally test whether the difference is statistically signifcantly different?

A hint I got from someone is that I might consider using only one model. I have no clue however.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/what-is-the-correct-way-to-test-for-significant-differences-between-coefficients). Does this help?

Comment: Is this time series data? Are these 2 products substitutes?

Answer (score 1):

This can be addressed by introducing a dummy variable and an interaction term.

Let
$Y = \text{Sales}$

$A = \text{Advertising}$

$X = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & \text{if Brand A}\\
       0 & \text{if Brand B}
     \end{array}
   \right.$

So we have continuous outcome $Y$, continuous covariate $A$, and dummy variable $X$.

We wish to determine whether the effect of advertising ($A$) on sales ($Y$) is the same between the two values of $X$. Graphically, this corresponds to the null hypothesis that regression lines for $X=0$ and $X=1$ are parallel.

We can test this hypothesis using the interaction model:

$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 A + \beta_2 X + \beta_3 AX$$
which can also be written as
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 A + X(\beta_2 + \beta_3 A)$$.

**If $X=0$ (Brand B):**

$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 A$$

**If $X=1$ (Brand A):**

$$ \begin{align} Y &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 A + \beta_2 + \beta_3 A\\
&= (\beta_0 + \beta_2) + (\beta_1 + \beta_3) A
\end{align}
$$

Our null hypothesis is that the slopes of the two lines are the same, so
$$\begin{align}
H_0 : \beta_1 &= \beta_1 + \beta_3\\
\Leftrightarrow \beta_3 &= 0
\end{align}$$

This means that to address whether the effect of advertising on sales is the same between brands, we can perform a t-test for $\beta_3$ in the interaction model.