How to determine or show if two solutions to linear regression are different
Assume that I have a system and that I can measure both the inputs and outputs of and that I can formulate a solution I want in the form of linear regression: $A \vec{x}=\vec{b}$.  Further assume that I've measured $A$ and $\vec{b}$ twice.  The first time I measure everything, $A_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{450 \times 45}$ and $\vec{b}_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{450 \times 1}$.  The second time, $A_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{450 \times 45}$ and $\vec{b}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{450 \times 1}$.  The entries in the $A$ and $\vec{b}$ are not the same.
I can solve both of these systems of equations to get $\vec{x}_1$, $\Sigma_{x_1}$, $\vec{x}_2$, and $\Sigma_{x_2}$.  Where the $\Sigma$ are the variance-covariance matrices for the solutions, $\vec{x}$.  I can think of two ways to argue that $\vec{x}_2$ is likely to be different from $\vec{x}_1$.

Compute the euclidean distance between $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$ and then do a Welch t-test on the distance.  This always shows extreme significance.  I think because of the curse of dimensionality.

Compute how (un)likely it would be to draw $\vec{x}_2$ from the distribution defined by $\vec{x}_1$ (and its $\Sigma$).  The likelihood is just the integral of all space as close to $\vec{x}_1$ as $\vec{x}_2$ or further away.  This seems asymmetric, so do the same for $\vec{x}_1$ drawn from $\vec{x}_2$ (and its $\Sigma$) and average them.  This seems less likely to suffer from the curse of dimensionality because I am weighting most of the space by practically zero.


Both of these methods function in that I can literally compute the results, but I've made them up ad hoc and I'd like to know if there are more established ways of computing/showing/determining/arguing that the vectors $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$ are different in a statistical sense.

Consider a system in which the input is the collection of your two measurements and the outputs are the collected results.  This system can be represented as a single measurement involving a $900\times 90$ matrix and an parameter estimate $\beta$ that is the concatenation of $x_1$ and $x_2.$ You simply need to test the hypothesis $x_1=x_2$ (that's a set of $45$ equalities), which is a standard and extremely well established technique.  What about your situation would preclude this straightforward solution?

Wouldn’t the single measurement be 900x45? 45 equalities is straightforward as you say, but in this situation, I’m using the parameters to reconstruct an image and I’m not sure what it means for the image if, for example, all the terms are significant but one. Your comment/question has made me think about whether looking at the individual coefficients will get me what I want, though.  Thank you.

It would be $450\times 90$ if the regressors $A$ had been identical in both cases.  But since you are estimating $90$ coefficients, you cannot reduce the second dimension.  I believe your question has been asked and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13112 (among others), where you can read the details.

I still do not understand the 900x90 part.  At the moment, I have two 450x45 matrices.  It isn't obvious how to put that data into a 900x90 matrix. No matter which way I do, half of the entries in the matrix are going to be unknown (zero?) because I literally do not have enough data to fill all of those entries.

They will be zeros.  The relationship is determined by the rules of matrix multiplication.  It can help to work it out with a tiny example, such as two sets of observations with one regressor (where $A$ is a $2\times 1$ matrix).

I suppose I could just make the $A$ matrix block-diagonal, but I don't see how that is any different from running two separate regressions and then comparing the coefficients.  What is the point of the single measurement construction?  Why does that matter?

Because it makes this a standard question in regression with standard, routine solutions implemented in all kinds of software: no special calculations or theory are needed.  For details see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12797 (it's the same question as yours).
